# XSL : Look up for XSL command retrieve an XML nodes list

Tags: xml, xslt, command

Is there in the XSL commands, a tool to retrieve a list of nodes
ex :

```
<Root>
    <Params>
      <First>1</First>
      <Second>2</Second>
      <Group>
        <Data>Example</Data>
        <Info>Show</Info>
      </Group>
    </Params>
</Root>
```

so ,
`<XSL:[Command] select="/Root/Params"/>` will give :

```
<Params>
  <First>1</First>
  <Second>2</Second>
  <Group>
    <Data>Example</Data>
    <Info>Show</Info>
  </Group>
</Params>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/Root/Params"/>
```

will do that (probably, since the context is not entirely clear).